# Fetch data only once, and then store it in local storage

Tags: reactjs, redux

So, I have an app where I'm fetching data users from jsonplaceholder using react-redux.

**The problem is**, everytime I refresh the page, the data also erased(?) (I'm sorry for my lack of vocab) and fetched again.

**The thing is**, I want it to not erased (again, sorry) and still there. I've tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580523/fetch-data-only-once-to-react-app-never-fetch-again-after-page-reloads) and I keep getting error, either it's `invalid assignment to const` or `is not defined`.

Is anybody here know how to keep the fetched data in local storage? Thanks before!

Comment: add your code and everyone can help you?

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh then your react state will go on the initial state. If you want to store the data and don.t want to erase it after refresh, then you have to use the localstore or some lightweight database (like some Persistant database). Then only your data will not erase after refresh.